# Take information submitted in a form on wordpress to python bot

Tags: python, wordpress

I currently am making a website using wordpress and have some pages where they can fill out their info for me using forminator pro. I want to know if it is possible to have a python bot connected to the website so I can use it to perform some tasks with their info. I've tried looking on youtube and on other forums but have been unable to find what I'm looking for. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like there isn't a straightforward "yes, just do this" option, at least not one that's easy to find. Here are a few suggestions to get you started, but they may only help if you're comfortable learning as you go. You're already on StackOverflow, so that's a sign that maybe you are ;)

**Security Considerations**

But first, a note about security. Although you've asked "[How] Can I do this?" you should also ask "Should I do this?", and the answer is likely to be somewhere between "It depends." and "Probably not." Regardless, if you haven't already, you should take a look at the official [hardening WordPress guidelines](https://wordpress.org/support/article/hardening-wordpress/) before you go live.

When you have a form on your website, you're getting some arbitrary data from visitors to your website. After very little time online, a significant portion of visitors to any website are malicious automated bots searching for security vulnerabilities. A lot of it is simple stuff like trying to put `'; SELECT * FROM USERS; --` into a text field to see if they can dump sensitive data from your database, but some activity may also be looking for a way to take over your hosting server. If you're taking content from a form, and then pushing it into a custom program that you made, there's a good chance you don't have the necessary level of input filtering and cleaning to ensure that those attacks won't get through.
This is also true if you were building a PHP plugin, or a python webapp, but both of those scenarios come with some recommended best practices that you'd hopefully stumble upon regarding cleaning untrusted input. But when you're trying to hack together a polyglot solution, those best practices rarely exist (or at least aren't easy to find or well documented), and there's a good chance you're not looking for them while trying to solve the problem.

A full list of security best practices and considerations for this solution would be too long and off topic to add here, but consider asking a follow up question (or searching for ones that are already answered) focused on input cleaning.

**Possible Solutions**

You may be able to use one of the available [Forminator integrations](https://wpmudev.com/docs/wpmu-dev-plugins/forminator/#integrations) to make this connection, although there isn't currently an obvious winner in the list. It looks like they also have a full-featured API, though that appears to be designed for other plugins to interact with it. Cross-language function calls introduce all sorts of headaches, so you probably don't want to do that unless you plan to spend a lot of time developing your python script further or if you're comfortable enough with PHP programming that you want to build (and maintain) a PHP-based wrapper for your python bot.

It's a bit clumsy, but using the Google Sheets integration to get the data into a sheet, and then having your python bot periodically check that sheet for changes via the sheets API may be one of the easier approaches. Alternatively, you could check whether Forminator supports [WP CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) and call WP CLI commands from your bot. Possibly your cleanest option with Forminator would be to use a cron job or a WordPress scheduled jobs plugin to run the Forminator export periodically, and send the result to your python bot for processing, but that might be resource intensive if you're trying to do it every few minutes (daily or weekly would be a sensible schedule if you're willing to wait that long).

If you're just getting started on this website, and you're not stuck with/committed to using Forminator, you could also look for a different forms solution that meets all your needs, including being compatible with your bot (whether that's because it has hooks that can call the bot, it has a RESTful API that you can easily query, it provides easily usable and schedulable exports, or makes the connection between the two easier in some other way). If looking for something other than Forminator is something you're considering, write down all your requirements, including the python bot, and make a list of options to assess for suitability before getting too tied into one option. You'll learn more about what you need an how to solve it by planning it out first than by just diving in (though you do eventually need to dive in -- not everything shows up during the planning phase).